# Parse.com and Facebook SDK issues

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I'm trying to use Parse's version of the Facebook SDK, but for some reason none of the PF_FB objects/methods are showing up except for `PF_FBRequest`. For example, `PF_FBRequestConnection` isn't showing up in XCode's autocomplete. I can see `PF_FBRequestConnection.h` in Parse's header files, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

I have `#import "Parse/Parse.h"` included at the top of the file... Am I supposed to import a different file to get access to Parse's version of the Facebook SDK?

So far, I've been able to use the Parse SDK to login through Facebook, so I think I have it installed correctly...

**More info**

In Xcode's autocomplete, only PF_Facebook, PF_FBDialog, PF_FBFrictionlessRequestSettings, PF_FBLoginDialog, PF_FBRequest, and PF_RequestState objects are available... I feel like another file needs to get imported or something and that's why the other objects/methods aren't showing up...

Alternatively, how could I use the stock Facebook SDK with Parse when I'm using Parse to login through Facebook? How can I get the active session from `handleOpenUrl` to the stock FB SDK?

**Another update**

See comment below - the issue appears to be related to importing the Parse framework into an existing project. Are you supposed to do anything extra to get the FB SDK to work beyond what's in the Parse Quick Start guide?

Comment: I've been trying to figure this issue out all day - I finally tried downloading Parse's "New Project" template and all the Facebook objects/methods worked just fine with that, so the problem I'm experiencing must have to do with importing the Parse SDK into an existing project. 

 

When importing the latest Parse SDK into an existing project, do you have to do anything extra to get access to the Facebook SDK? I followed all the steps listed on the Quick Start guide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like we're missing the broader FB APIs in our main header.  You can manually get them in your project with:

```
#import "Parse/PF_FacebookSDK.h"
```

That should allow you to use them yourself until we get it updated in the SDK.

Sorry for the inconvenience!